# How to addEventListener to listen for push notifications with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a website that updates automatically when I get a message and sends me a push notification. I am trying to create a chrome extension that can detect when I get that push notification and do something when it happens.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be outputting to console. Is something wrong or do I need to change something about my manifest?

**inject.js**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
//I want to do a thing here
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('This push event has data: ', event.data.text());
  } else {
    console.log('This push event has no data.');
  }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Push notifcation detector",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Do a thing!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://mywebsite.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "./js/inject.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": false,
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/**/*.png"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "./images/icons/icon.png",
            "48": "./images/icons/icon.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "./images/icons/icon.png",
        "48": "./images/icons/icon.png",
        "128": "./images/icons/icon.png"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to run some sort of background page to receive the message. For the dropdowns, as far as I know, Chrome creates and drops the pages when you select and de-select, or when the browser is on the configured page. By default, it's not going to work because the page isn't running constantly.

This may help: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I will look into having a background page. Attaching a listener for events just means I have to have a tab open on that website which I would have to anyways to get the push notifications. My code should work for this though?

Comment: The code looks fine, but I haven't done this actual thing before.

I don't know how you would register for your background page to receive these messages. If the background page has a url then that should be enough, but if not you may need to do something with the backend.